# How can I make appear RecyclerView with an animation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

In my app if I press a button (the green one on the screenshot) I set my RecyclerView from height 0 to 600 and even if I re-press the same button it disappear by setting it height to 0.

But actually it's ugly to see because it's appear instantly so I would like to add an animation to it like it's growing up slowly or bouncing, I don't know, something that would make it nicer. Is there a way to make something like this?

[image]
[image]

Here is my code where I make appear or disappear the RecyclerView:

```
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mRecyclerViewBOT.getLayoutParams();
            if(params.height == 0) {
                params.height = 600;
                mRecyclerViewBOT.setLayoutParams(params);
            }else {
                params.height = 0;
                mRecyclerViewBOT.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
parentView.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);
```

where parentView is the view containing your recyclerView